# React Native useState not working inside of watchPositionAsync

Tags: reactjs, react-native, use-state, react-native-maps

I am trying to use React-Native-Maps Polyline. However I can not figure out what I am doing wrong when it comes to adding new coordinates to the array as the user moves around. My code is as follows:

```
const Walk = () => {
    const [location, setLocation] = useState();
    const [coords, setCoords] = useState();
    const [last, setLast] = useState();
    const [watch, setWatch] = useState();
    const { onWalk, distance, setDistance, isPaused } = useContext(WalkContext);

    const getInitLocation = async () => {
        const { granted } = await Location.requestPermissionsAsync();
        if (!granted) return;

        const currentLocation = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
        setLocation(currentLocation.coords);

        const firstLast = {
            latitude: currentLocation.coords.latitude,
            longitude: currentLocation.coords.longitude
        };

        setLast(firstLast);
        setCoords([firstLast]);
    }

    const watchPosition = async () => {
        let newLoc;
        setWatch(
            newLoc =  await Location.watchPositionAsync({
                accuracy: Location.Accuracy.High,
                timeInterval: 1000000,
                distanceInterval: 100
            }, position => {
                const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
                const newCoord = {
                    latitude,
                    longitude
                }

                if (last) {
                    const newDist = distanceBetween(
                        last.latitude,
                        last.longitude,
                        newCoord.latitude,
                        newCoord.longitude
                    );
                    setDistance(distance + newDist);
                    setLast(newCoord);
                }

                const newCoords = [...coords, newCoord];
                setCoords(newCoords);
            
                setLocation(position.coords);
            }, 
            err => console.log(err))
        );
    }

    const stopWatching = () => {
        if (watch) {
            watch.remove();
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!location) {
            getInitLocation();
        }

        if (isPaused) {
            watchPosition();
        } else {
            stopWatching();
        }

    }, [isPaused]);
}
```

The map works great except that I am struggling to add new coords correctly to the coords state. It seems like it only adds the initial and the very last coord to the array. Any help is appreciated. Im sure it is a simple mistake but I cant figure it out.

Comment: are you setting states inside of another setState function?

Answer (score 0):

Hey you are using setWatch() incorrectly it only accept data or function which need to return data
and I can see that you are not returning anything in useWatch()